# Coordinate ring is a product of rings iff the variety is disconnected

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Consider a coordinate ring $k[V]$ for variety $V \subset \mathbb{A}^n$. How to prove that $k[V]$ is direct product of rings iff V is disconnected?

Moreover how to see it geometrically and what's the intuition behind this fact, because it's may be very obvious (it seems like we have two system of polynomials which are in some sense "coprime" and like in chinese reminder theorem the quotient ring is isomorphic to product of quotient rings, but may be what i've wrote is very stupid)

Answer (score 1):

Write $A$ the coordinate ring of $V$. If $V$ is disconnected we can write $V = X \sqcup Y$ where $X = Z(I)$ and $Y = Z(J)$. Then, $Z(J + I) = \emptyset$ so that $J + I = A$. Moreover, $Z(IJ) = V$ so that $\sqrt{IJ} = 0$. Since these ideals are finitely generated $I^nJ^n = 0$ for sufficiently large $n$. Since $Z(I) = Z(I^n)$, it also follows that $I^n + J^n = A$.

Now fix $f \in I^n$ and $g \in J^n$ so that $f + g = 1$ and $fg = 0$. It follows that $f$ and $g$ are idempotents in $A$ and that $A = Af \times Ag$.

Comment: That's not true that $\sqrt{IJ} = 0$, because it implies that $IJ = 0$ because $IJ \subset \sqrt{IJ}$. Moreover, why $Z(I) = Z(I^n)$?We can only say that $Z(I) \subset Z(I^n)$. And the main question, how you got that $f, g$ are idempotents?